# Как использовать GitLab CI для Qt проектов

Tags: qt, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Разрабатываю приложение с помощью Qt для Windows (основная ОС) и Linux (VM). Проект лежит в репозитории GitLab.

**Рутинная задача**: реализовать правки заказчика, собрать приложение и отправить бинарники. Сейчас это работает так: под Windows я собираю у себя, под Linux - VM.

**Возник вопрос**: как можно упростить этот процесс?

На днях открыл для себя GitLab CI. Описание очень понравилось, но пока я не разобрался, как это работает. Если я правильно понял, то GitLab при коммите тестирует, собирает и развертывает приложение.

Поскольку слова Docker, Runner и т.д. для меня новые слова и документации/примера для Qt я не нашел - не понимаю, **как это работает**?

Моя идея:

1. Сделать коммит релизной версии
2. GitLab CI автоматически соберет мое приложение для Windows и Linux
3. Версия для скачивания станет доступна заказчику

Могу ли я реализовать такую схему с помощью только инструментов GitLab? Без сторонних серверов и виртуальных машин.

Если нет, то как можно?

Возможно, я плохо исследовал интернет и ответ на мой вопрос уже есть. Пожалуйста, поделитесь ссылкой или примером.

**UPD 1:** Начал ковырять GitLab, чтобы разобраться.

Первое, нашел тестовый docker образ - https://hub.docker.com/r/garthk/qt-build

Второе, создал в репозитории файл .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: garthk/qt-build:bionic-5.12.0

stages:
    - build
    - push-latest

variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE:        ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}
    DOCKER_LATEST_IMAGE: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest

#
# Make sure we are logged into the GitLab container registry for each script.
#
before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_BUILD_TOKEN} registry.gitlab.com

#
# Build a docker image using the files in the 'docker/' subdirectory.
#
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - docker build -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} docker/
        - docker push ${DOCKER_IMAGE}

#
# Tag the master image as 'latest'.
#
push-latest:
    stage: push-latest
    script:
        - docker pull ${DOCKER_IMAGE}
        - docker tag ${DOCKER_IMAGE} ${DOCKER_LATEST_IMAGE}
        - docker push ${DOCKER_LATEST_IMAGE}
    only:
        - master
```

После коммита запустился build (pipeline?) и выдал ошибку:

```
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_BUILD_TOKEN} registry.gitlab.com
/bin/bash: line 76: docker: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Мне нужно установить Docker на свой компьютер и виртуальную Linux машину, чтобы это работало?

Или GitLab уже все может из коробки и мне нужно что-то настроить? Смущают переменные, которые я нигде не инициализировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При запуске контейнера в нем уже находится ваш репозиторий. Вам нужно только запустить сборку.

Пример:

```
build:
  # указываем образ в котором будет происходить сборка
  image: garthk/qt-build:bionic-5.12.0

  # указываем команды для сборки
  script:
   - qmake -makefile
   - make

  # загружаем собранные файлы в gitlab
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - ./build
```